# Check duplicate column data using Jquery filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Notice that my first two table Data (Apple and Orange) are set to read-only. And I do have function for dynamic adding of row.
see this [FIDDLE FOR DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cDa3N/5/)

If the user click the `Save button`, all `input field` that detect duplicate of data from database or last duplicate of data from row which dynamically added, border-color will change to red.

```
$("#save").off("click").on("click",function(){
var $rows = $('#myTable tbody tr:not(:hidden)');
        $rows.each(function(){
        var $id = $(this).find('td input[type=\'text\']');
            alert($id.val());
        //Im stuck here, for checking column data is duplicate.
      });
});
```

Im looking forward on using Jquery filter , like this :

```
$( "li" ).filter( "DUPLICATE DATA()" ).css( "border-color", "red" );
```

Comment: do you mean making sure there isn't multiple rows with the same "Name"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am assuming you want to target the "Name" column, although you could easily change this to target all columns.

Basically, you want to go through the `input` elements, keeping a reference to the values you've already reviewed:

```
$("#save").off("click").on("click",function(){
    var existing = [];
    var duplicates = $('#myTable td:nth-child(3) input').filter(function() {
        var value = $(this).val();
        if (existing.indexOf(value) >= 0) {
            return $(this);
        }
        existing.push(value);
    });
    duplicates.closest('tr').css('background-color', 'red');
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8y54wwuj/2/)

**Edit**: To avoid marking a read-only line as a duplicate, the process is a little less straightforward

```
$("#save").off("click").on("click",function(){
    // Clear status of all elements
    $('#myTable tr').css('background-color', 'none');

    // Get all values first (Apple, Orange, etc) as strings
    var allValues = $('#myTable td:nth-child(3) input').map(function() {
        return $(this).val();
    }).toArray();

    // Iterate unique values individually, to avoid marking a read-only input as duplicate
    var processedValues = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < allValues.length; i++) {
        var value = allValues[i];
        if (value != '' && processedValues.indexOf(value) >= 0) continue;
        var inputs = $('#myTable td:nth-child(3) input').filter(function() { return $(this).val() == value; });
        // Check if this value is in one of the readonly
        var readOnlyInput = inputs.filter(function() { return $(this).is('[readonly]'); });
        if (readOnlyInput.length) {
            inputs.not(readOnlyInput).closest('tr').css('background-color', 'red');
        } else {
            inputs.not(':first').closest('tr').css('background-color', 'red');
        }
        processedValues.push(value);
    }
});
```

[Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8y54wwuj/12/)

Comment: td:nth-child(3) input is no working on IE I guess. Can you help me work around, using the code posted above. thanks :)

Comment: If add "Orange" before "Orange" that is readonly. The input that will have red borderline is the input that is read-only w/c is wrong. I dont want the read-only input(supposedly from database to be mark as duplicate or to have red borderline)

Comment: `td:nth-child` might not be working in older versions of IE because of the jQuery version you're using (2.1). Visit the [jQuery download page](http://jquery.com/download/) for more information about browser support, and which version is right for you.

Comment: If I add "Orange" before "Orange", nothing mark as duplicate("User input w/c has value "Orange now should be mark as duplicate").I dont want the read-only input to be mark as duplicate, but I want the row of input field that tries to duplicate it to had red borderline or to be mark as duplicate. :)

Comment: If I understand correctly, adding "Orange" before the existing "Orange" should mark the new "Orange" row. That's the behavior I'm getting from the code. Maybe we need the comparison to trim the text and not be case-sensitive?

Comment: A weird behavior occurred when you had an empty row in the middle. My bad, I was attempting to skip processing of empty values with `return` instead of `continue`. Updated answer :)

Comment: No. my bad sir.haha I just removed this line of code `   $('#myTable tr').css('background-color', 'none');`,  :) So excited to test the code, so Im not able to read yor code on the first place. :) Thanks a lot.

Comment: can i add another condition here? I need to have a condition where the `if` and `else` is false @cypherkaz

Comment: please see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26967468/trying-to-catch-another-condition-for-boolean-false-value

Comment: Saw your question. I believe you're trying to determine whether a certain value was found more than one time during the processing part. You're looking in the wrong part of the code (the `if (readOnlyInput.length)` will only tell you the number of inputs marked as readonly for that specific value). Please see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pk4qqx1m/1/)

Comment: Wow thanks for your answer and explanation. Actually I am confused on that using as if condition.Really thanks sir. Why not post this fiddle so I can mark this as answer. :)