# Trying to catch another condition for boolean false value

Tags: jquery

[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7n28z85z/1/)

My flag always has a result of true , and I dont know why. I need to get the flag value 'true', if nothing is duplicate.Please see fiddle above:

```
  if (readOnlyInput.length) {
            flag = true;
            inputs.not(readOnlyInput).closest('tr').css('background-color', 'red');
        } else {
             flag = true;
            inputs.not(':first').closest('tr').css('background-color', 'red');
        }
```

To does who downvoted, I do set the flag to true to `true` because the condition is `true`, My problem now is what to add condition so i can set it `false`.Setting those flag to true is correct. Now, I should have add condition so that I can set it to false, but i dont know what condition I will add.

Comment: You are always setting it to `flag = true;`

Comment: @Satpal Yes I see, but i want to add another condition so I can set the `flag` to `false`

Comment: @bumbumpaw, have you even tried the code I posted?

Comment: @YohanesKhosiawan许先汉 Yes, but the boolean value is always  returning "false"

Answer (score 1):

Try to initialize your `flag` to `true` in the beginning of the iteration.
And if the current entry in the iteration violates the rule (a duplicate), set the `flag` to `false`.

**UPDATED**:

```
  $(document).on("click", '.tdAdd', function () {
    var counter = $('#myTable tbody tr').length + 1;
    var newRow = $("<tr>");
    var cols = "";
    cols += '<td><input type="button" value="Add Row" class="tdAdd"/></td>';
    cols += '<td><input type="button" value="Delete" class="tdAdd"/></td>';
    cols += '<td><input type="text" name="name' + counter + '"/></td>';
    cols += '<td><input type="text" name="price' + counter + '"/></td>';
    newRow.append(cols);
    newRow.insertAfter($(this).closest("tr"));
});

$("#save").off("click").on("click", function () {
    // Clear status of all elements
    $('#myTable tr').css('background-color', 'none');

    // Get all values first (Apple, Orange, etc) as strings
    var allValues = $('#myTable td').filter(function () {
        return $(this).closest('tr').children('td').index(this) === 2;
    })
        .find('input').map(function () {
        return $(this).val();
    }).toArray();
    // Iterate unique values individually, to avoid marking a read-only input as duplicate
    var flag = true;
    for (var i = 0; i < allValues.length; i++) {
        var value = allValues[i];
        if (value == '') continue; //blank field
        var inputs = $('#myTable td').filter(function () {
            return $(this).closest('tr').children('td').index(this) === 2;
        })
            .find('input').filter(function () {
            return $(this).val() == value;
        });
        // Check if this value is in one of the readonly
        var readOnlyInput = inputs.filter(function () {
            return $(this).is('[readonly]');
        });
        if (inputs.length > 1) {
            flag = false;
            if (readOnlyInput.length >= 1) {
                inputs.not(readOnlyInput).closest('tr').css('background-color', 'red');
            } else {
                inputs.not(':first').closest('tr').css('background-color', 'red');
            }
        }
        //console.log('Finished processing of ' + value);
    }
    alert(flag);
});
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7n28z85z/3/ upadated fiddle if add two different values flag is always false

Comment: Yes, but the boolean value is always  returning "false"  @Yohanes Khosiawan 许先汉

Comment: no, you didn't, @bumbumpaw, please recheck your code at the fiddle, it's still not the one I posted!

Comment: see this sir http://jsfiddle.net/7n28z85z/4/, If I try to add "Orange" before "Orange" w/c is readonly, the readonly "Orange" value will be mark as red now w/c is wrong(as those readonly  are supposed to values from database) @Yohanes Khosiawan 许先汉

Comment: another issue.. try to check the update out, @bumbumpaw

Comment: sir just need to test this. Wait for the "check for answer" sir.thanks :)

Comment: Sir another issue, Apple,Orange,(Berry,Berry,Dog,Cat) Berry do have mark, but the value of flag should be false(now is true).

Comment: This issue only trigger now because of my added flag, on the original code this is working fine on my condition so I dont what to add condition that will make it return false/

Comment: yep, you just need to move the `flag=true` outside the iteration (see the update) and it should be fine

Answer (score 0):

Because you have in both `if` and `else` the definition of `flag=true`

Either go with

```
if (readOnlyInput.length) {
    flag = true;
    inputs.not(readOnlyInput).closest('tr').css('background-color', 'red');
} else {
    flag = else;
    inputs.not(':first').closest('tr').css('background-color', 'red');
}
```

Or

```
if (readOnlyInput.length) {
    flag = else;
    inputs.not(readOnlyInput).closest('tr').css('background-color', 'red');
} else {
    flag = true;
    inputs.not(':first').closest('tr').css('background-color', 'red');
}
```

Depends on you :)

Comment: Yes I see, setting those flag to true is correct. Now, I should have add condition that I can set it to false, but i dont know what condition I will add.